# How do you use small caps in Pages?

Tags: pages, font, formatting

I don't see any obvious options for small caps in Pages, either under styles or text formatting.  Do I need a special font, or does Pages have small caps capability at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe [this link to the documentation of Pages](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Pages/3.0/en/c5pg19.html) helps you out?

> 1. Choose Format > Font > Capitalization and choose an option from the submenu.
> 2. Choose Small Caps to change the text to smaller capitals with larger capitals for uppercase letters

Comment: It's also buried on the inspector window - but knowing the menu path is faster in most cases than navigating amongst the tabs of that control element.

Comment: Note, however, that this fakes small-caps (scaled down versions of the full caps that look rather anemic).  To get proper small-caps, you had to open the Font panel (cmd-t) and then open the Font Panel Actions (small sprocket on the bottom left) and select typography.  This **used** to allow you to use the real small-caps provided with OTF fonts, but it has been broken for about a year now... has Apple abandoned high-quality typography?  (See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4403525 for some details.)

Answer (score 0):

"Real" small caps, as noted by @mforbes in the comment on the other answer ***are*** available, but only for a small subset of the installed fonts.  (One I found is Avenir.  I was wishing for it in Helvetica Neue.)  As described in [this blog post](https://www.zeichenschatz.net/typografie/real-small-caps-and-other-opentype-features-in-apple-pages-keynote-and-numbers.html) and the comment above, *If* the feature is available for the font, you can open the OSX Font panel (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> or `Format->Font->Show Fonts...` in most apps) and select `Typography...` under the `"gear"` menu.  Look especially for `Lower Case`

As the linked blog post notes, for the Pages app in particular, you can also create and save a "character style" to make it faster to select.  Other than that, this should work the same in any app that uses the standard font panel such as TextEdit, Bean, etc.

Comment: On reflection, there are so few fonts that support it, so I think @Michiel's suggestion of Format->Font->Capitalization is the best way to go in 10.14.  Unfortunately that capability isn't standard across the OS, so it works in Pages, but you can't do it in, say, TextEdit.